# WPF TextBox MaxLength -- Is there any way to bind this to the Data Validation Max Length on the bound field?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-annotations, maxlength

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public String SomeProperty { ... }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" MaxLength="50" />
```

Is there any way to avoid setting the MaxLength of the TextBox to match up my ViewModel (which could change since it is in a different assembly) and have it automatically set the max length based on the StringLength requirement?

Answer (score 19):

I used a [Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726531%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to connect the TextBox to its bound property's validation attribute (if any).  The behavior looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Set the maximum length of a TextBox based on any StringLength attribute of the bound property
/// </summary>
public class RestrictStringInputBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, args) => setMaxLength();
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    private void setMaxLength()
    {
        object context = AssociatedObject.DataContext;
        BindingExpression binding = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

        if (context != null && binding != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = context.GetType().GetProperty(binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                var att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;
                if (att != null)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.MaxLength = att.MaximumLength;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see, the behavior simply retrieves the data context of the text box, and its binding expression for "Text".  Then it uses reflection to get the "StringLength" attribute.  Usage is like this:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:RestrictStringInputBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

</UserControl>
```

You could also add this functionality by extending `TextBox`, but I like using behaviors because they are modular.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not going to write the code out completely myself, one idea is to create your own [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) that will take the property name and reflect over looking for a `StringLengthAttribute`.

If the attribute exists, attempt to bind the target to that value (using reflection). If not, then bind 0 to the target value (0 is default, i.e. no max).

Comment: I've had a hell of a time trying to figure out how to write this extension up so that it does what you say.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a property in that same viewmodel called SomePropertyMaxLength and then bind the MaxLength property to that property.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" MaxLength="{Binding SomePropertyMaxLength}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I really wanted to avoid going through and adding additional properties that reflect over my metadata and then going through all my xaml and binding to those properties... I was hoping for an "under the covers" type of way... perhaps by attached behaviors?

Comment: You can change your "SomeProperty" to be an object which contains the string value and the maxlength value and then bind to those properties respectively. This way you won't have to create new properties but you will still have to go through the xaml changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Markup extension is definitely the way to go.
I am creating a subclass of BindingDecoratorBase called Binding which has a model DataType dependency property. As MarkupExtensions are created during InitializeComponent() there is no way to determine the DataContext as it will not have been set yet.

Providing the model type permits reflective access to attributes defined on the model.
This permits:

- Setting MaxLength for TextBoxes.
- Setting StringFormat for TextBlocks.
- Setting the default Converter depending on member data type.
- Adding required validation. Using either the binding's ValidationRules or by setting ValidatesOnDataErrors.

The markup looks like:
Text="{PO:Binding DataType=model:modAccount, Path=SubAccount}"

Formatting, MaxLength, and Conversion rolled into one package with no need to change anything as the model classes change.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have your model only to accept a max # chars:

```
private string _MyText { get; set; }
public string MyText { get => _MyText; set => _MyText = value?.Substring(0, 
Math.Min(value.Length, 15)); }

Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"
```

Comment: should be 'value.Length - 1'