# Apply Entity Framework HasMaxLength to WPF TextBox MaxLength?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, ef-code-first

I use Entity Framework 6 Code First with Fluent API, and some of the properties of data classes have max length defined through HasMaxLength.

In WPF, in order to enforce the input constraints, I add MaxLength in the XAML for TextBox. At the moment, I have to define something like 40 characters for EF through HasMaxLength, and then define 40 again in the XAML.

It there built-in way in .NET Framework or some 3rd party component that can apply what in HasMaxlength of EF to MaxLength in WPF?

Comment: [WPF TextBox MaxLength — Is there any way to bind this to the Data Validation Max Length on the bound field?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14761626/3110834)

Comment: may be [How to Implement Max Length in WPF, Entity Framework Using MVVM Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=716350&av=1057698) will enlighten