# WPF: How find all binding relation

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

In my TextBoxs I binding to dataRowView. My binding relation is:

TextBox --binding-- DataRowView

or

TextBox --binding-- Property --binding-- DataRowView

Sometimes I don't create directly binding beetwen TextBox and DataRowView.

I need set MaxLength in TextBox. 
In first relation for set MaxLength in TextBox I using [WPF TextBox MaxLength -- Is there any way to bind this to the Data Validation Max Length on the bound field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745325/wpf-textbox-maxlength-is-there-any-way-to-bind-this-to-the-data-validation-ma)
but I found problem with second relation. I don't idea what find a datarowView when I binding  TextBox to Property and Property to DataRowView.

Simple Code - xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:Behaviors x:Key="BehaviorsStringInput" x:Shared="False">
        <l:RestrictStringInputBehavior/>
    </l:Behaviors>
    <Style x:Key="tb" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="l:SupplementaryInteraction.Behaviors" Value="StaticResource BehaviorsStringInput}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">        
    <TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding ElementName=_this,Path=MyText}" Width="300" Height="20" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource tb}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb2" Width="300" Height="20" Margin="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

cs:

```
private DataRowView dr;
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty;   
//    
//...
//
    Binding bin = new Binding("TextValue");
    bin.Source = dr;
    bin.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bin);

    Binding bin2 = new Binding("TextValue");
    bin2.Source = dr;
    bin2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    this.SetBinding(MainWindow.MyTextProperty, bin);
```

RestrictStringInput:

```
public class RestrictStringInputBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, args) => setmaxlength();
        base.OnAttached();
    }
    private void setmaxlength()
    {
        object context = AssociatedObject.DataContext;
        BindingExpression binding = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);            
        if (context != null && binding != null)
        {
            if (context is DataRowView)
            {
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)context;
                // bingin.ParentBinding.Path.Path for tb1 has TextValue value and is correct, but for tb2 value is MyText.
                DataColumn dc = drv.Row.Table.Columns[binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path];
                if (dc != null)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.MaxLength = dc.MaxLength;
                }
```

Comment: Can you add your code example?

Comment: So how should the maximum length be calculated? Why not just bind it to another property, or to the data row view (using a converter to extract the desired length)?

Comment: @user1672994: I added very simple code with my problem.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: Sometimes I can't create binding in userControl when DataRowView is null (I'm begginer in binding).

Comment: Well, bindings are usually set in xaml, and they're rarely if ever 'inspected' to fetch more information. Why don't you just bind `MaxLength` to a separate property? What does the view-model code for this view look like?