# How to get column max length using ef6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I working with DB First model through designer and EF6 in VB.net, VS2015.

I have a dialog win form with various text boxes, non are data bound.

The dialog is used to get Address info, This address info may or may not be persisted to an SQL DB thus the not data bound design.

My problem is that I want to define the max length for each textbox based on the EF DBContext ShipHdrs columns. Now using the old ADODB.Datasets I could do

```
txtS2Name.MaxLength = dtCust.Columns("S2Name").MaxLength.
```

So how do I do this under ef6?

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Comment: See if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745325/wpf-textbox-maxlength-is-there-any-way-to-bind-this-to-the-data-validation-ma/14761626#14761626) helps.

Comment: It is Winforms desktop app

Comment: The post suggested is getting the max length of a bound text box, my text boxes are not bound, thank you for the suggestion.