# Extending TextBox in WPF C# to use MaxLength

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to do this in a WPF project:
[WPF TextBox MaxLength -- Is there any way to bind this to the Data Validation Max Length on the bound field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745325/wpf-textbox-maxlength-is-there-any-way-to-bind-this-to-the-data-validation-ma)

That is, to extend a TextBox to have a default MaxLength based on the Data Annotations for that field.

I have added the package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf to my project:

I’ve then defined a User Control as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test_File_Creation.UserControlTFC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_File_Creation" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:RestrictStringInputBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

The RestrictStringInputBehavior function is similar to the example.

Now, on the Form I’ve got several TextBox(es), I have this definition:

```
xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Test_File_Creation"
```

But, I’m unable to figure out how to get UserControl to work.  The RestrictStringInputBehavior function is never getting called. I don't seem to be properly invoking the UserControl.

What is the proper way to extend a WPF TextBox to have it use the MaxLength property from the Data Annotation?

Comment: You don't need a `UserControl`, just use the `TextBox` control. Also, you need to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to some property that has the attribute for length (`[Required, StringLength(50)]`)

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I already have the [MaxLength(100)], etc on the fields (instead of StringLength())and I already have this for the binding: <TextBox  Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=dataname, Mode=TwoWay}"/>. I'm looking to avoid adding a MaxLength on this if it is already defined in the Data Annotations.